# SharePoint site not opening in IE

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I created one SharePoint site collection in SP2013. When I'm trying to open that site in `IE` when entering the credentials got a message

> "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you."

But same URL works on the other browsers. In IE it's not working after deleting the cookies also.

Comment: Can you try , opening private session of IE ?

Comment: I tried. It's not working.

Comment: Can you check your credential manager. I feel in IE its taking credentials which you do not have access. As you are able to access the same using other browser.

Comment: I checked credential manager Bhaskar. Same issue again!

Comment: @vijayg    Have you set  proxy in internet browser ?

Comment: @Dipen  Some SP sites working fine in IE but some sites not accessible.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try =>
Sp Change User Url

```
"Yoursiteurl"+ /_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true
```

try to login again...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Internet Options -> Security -> Select Internet or Intranet Zone -< Custom Level -> User Authentication -> Prompt for User Name Password.

Try this setting you will be prompted for credentials. Enter same credentials as you provide in other browser.

Comment: I tried with above option ankit. It's  not working.

Comment: Did u get pop up asking credentials after changing IE settings?
Site is Intranet or Internet hosted?
How many domains do u have on AD?